# Do I need a database for my nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, database, parsing, heatmap

I need to create a heatmap that displays density regions corresponding to Ipv6 addresses in the world. I can populate this heatmap (densities) by parsing a csv file and filtering for Ipv6 addresses and the associated lat,long coordinates.

Do I need a database to store this filtered information? Or can I write my application (the client side) in such a way that every time I go to the index.html page, the client side processes this csv file and populates the heat map? Also, there's a caveat that the csv file can be changed. Wouldn't that mean if I were using a db, I would need to repopulate the db with new data from the new csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is really up to you. You can definitely perform the parsing process of the csv file everytime on the client side as you're thinking. If it's a time consuming process then it might be better left to the server to perform this step and then just serve the results to the client.

Here are a few scenarios to wrap your head around...

1) **Client Side**. This is your idea. Server sends index.html and data.csv to client browser. And data is parsed and served on client side.

Pros: Simple server side logic.

Cons: Puts a lot of work on the client! (Hope they're not using a mobile device). Data is parsed client side for every request.

2) **Server Side**. Server parses data.csv and stores result in memory. Server sends index.html and parsed data in memory upon request.

Pros: No processing on client side. Minimal processing on server side (parsed once).

Cons: Stored in server memory. Will have to re-parse every time server starts. Unless it takes a long time to parse the data, this should be insignificant.

3) **Server Side + DB**. Server parses data.csv and commits results to database. Server sends index.html and parsed data upon request.

Pros: No processing on client side. Minimal processing on server side (parsed once).

Cons: Database for storing a simple static dataset as described above seems like overkill IMO.

I like scenario #2 personally (if it wasn't obvious). This is my opinion, hope it helps you decision.

---

To help answer your question about passing the server data to the client...

This depends mainly on what you're using on the server side. Node/Express, ASP.Net MVC, etc?

I suppose you have 2 scenarios for this (more decisions!).

1) index.html is a static file that is served up by the backend. If this is the case, you'll have some javascript in that file that will call back out to your server after the page loads to request that heatmap data. This call is where your other endpoint will come into play. Once it gets the data - you can guess the rest - it passes it to your heatmap library to do it's thing. So that REST endpoint you mentioned would do it's parsing and manipulation and return a JSON result. The script in your index.html will use JQuery to call out to that endpoint on your server with $.get().

2) index.html is not a static file. Instead it's an endpoint that generates html (and javascript). You would put everything into this one call. It would parse and manipulate the CSV (if it wasn't already done when the server started), and generate a response which will consist of the HTML for you page and script tags as well containing all the javascript. You'd set a javascript variable equal to the data. When the page loads, you would pass the data in the variable to the heatmap library.

Your thoughts are more aligned with scenario 1 I think. I have a feeling that this information might confuse you even more, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive answer. 
I am thinking processing on the server side might be the best option since I am also defining another REST endpoint that returns the lat,long coordinates within a bounding box (imagine a box on the map that the user specifies on the client side, and you want to return to the user all the coordinates of Ipv6 addresses within that box). What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think you have the right idea! The endpoint would take in your bounding box dimensions that were drawn client side, such as lat long of upper left of box, and lat long of lower right of box. With those inputs, you can loop through all your Ipv6 coordinates and return the ones that fall inside the box. Apologies if this is too much detail. I'd hate to take away the fun of figuring it out.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! :) @Theo

Comment: I do have a lingering question. I am using a js library for rendering the heatmap. Since the value for the densities (which are used by this heatmap api to draw a heatmap) are calculated on the server side, while the heatmap is rendered on the client side (include the heatmap js script in the index.html file), how do I send this calculated density from the server side to be used by this heatmap js script on the client side?

Comment: FYI - I've appended to my answer to help with your question.

Comment: thank you for all the information. Actually, I need to use the endpoint to display the data to the user in a single page javascript application, would that mean that my html file is not static? Since it first starts out as a heatmap (imagine a map that has heat densities, which I would need to populate as well given the csv file that I parse), and then once a user makes an input of the bounding box, that page changes to display the result of the bounding box input.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that depends on you and the performance of the former and latter.

Relying on the application to do the heavy lifting every time it's loaded might work fine if it doesn't take too long to load.

Otherwise you can have your application parse the CSV file and store the data in a database.  The question is, will the CSV file be transient?  If so you may want to the former and just to parse it every time the application is loaded.

Otherwise, you're free to store the data in a database and have your application query the database to display the results on the map.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules!!  But lots to consider.

How long does it take to parse/load and initialize the application?  You will have to incur that cost on every single request, if you load the data off the filesystem.

How often is the data set being changed?  If it is intensive to load the dataset you could have your application load it into memory and serve requests using the in memory version.   Then when it is updated the service will have to be notified so it can update its in memory version.

Are there any other ways that might work? Could you render your dataset to an svg or something and have a web server serve that static content?

If you choose to use a DB to store the dataset that your clients see, then it has to be updated when the data is changed for the clients to see it :)